# Idiomatic expression about the insignificance of details

Tags: expressions, idioms, popular-refrains

I'm trying to find an idiomatic expression that discards the importance of little details for seeing at the big picture. In Spanish we have a saying that goes something like "Sometimes the trees do not let us see the forest." I was wondering if there is a similar expression that's used in written English.

Comment: *You can't see the wood for the trees*, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English you have:

***[can't see the wood for the trees:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+see+the+wood+for+the+trees)***

> Cannot see, understand, or focus on a situation in its entirety due to being preoccupied with minor details.
>
> - *The way he's obsessing over one doorknob when we're renovating the entire house makes me think that he can't see the wood for the trees.*

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: In US English I think this is more often *can't see the **forest** for the trees*. *Wood* cisatlantically tends to signify the product.

Comment: So which one is it? Can't see the wood for the trees, or can't see the forest for the trees?

Comment: OP apparently first asks for an expression speaking about ignoring, not being preoccupied with, the minor details. / Giving the virtual word-for-word translation of a gloss isnot really ELU standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - you are just getting it wrong, read the Spanish translation.

Comment: Use *wood* for BrE and *forest* for AmE. Alternatitvely, just use *forest* since it would be understood by a BrE speaker.

Comment: If one assumes that OP wants 'an expression addressing a situation where focusing on minor details prevents one seeing the big picture', as their second statement (but not their first) implies, this was answered on ELU 7+ years ago. Easily ascertained by checking for 'wood + trees'.